# Are there any performance advantages in using `unreachable!` vs `panic!`?

Tags: rust

Is the existence of `unreachable!` macro purely for the sake of clarity when reading code, or does it provide any functional advantages?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes the [`unreachable!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) (and [`unimplemented!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unimplemented.html) too) are purely for clarity. They are [implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/77d096a2bb3f914f33a5daf10bfe855d0011e57e/src/libcore/macros.rs#L481-L493) to directly forward to `panic!`.

```
#[macro_export]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
macro_rules! unreachable {
    () => ({
        panic!("internal error: entered unreachable code")
    });
    ($msg:expr) => ({
        unreachable!("{}", $msg)
    });
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => ({
        panic!(concat!("internal error: entered unreachable code: ", $fmt), $($arg)*)
    });
}

#[macro_export]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
macro_rules! unimplemented {
    () => (panic!("not yet implemented"))
}
```

Not to be confused with the [`unreachable` *intrinsic*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.unreachable.html) (accessible in stable Rust via the [`unreachable`](https://docs.rs/crate/unreachable) or [`debug_unreachable`](https://docs.rs/crate/debug_unreachable) crates), which unsafely asserts a branch is totally unreachable. This allows the branch to be completely removed when optimizing. It could lead to undefined behavior if the assertion turns out to be wrong, compared with `unreachable!()` which only panics.

Comment: [unreachable_unchecked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.unreachable_unchecked.html)  is now the best way to access this. The crates are not longer needed.